# Does datatype support constant parameters?

Tags: dafny

Say I have the following datatype:

`datatype Tree = Genesis | Node(parent:Tree, time: nat)`

For my application it is safe to assume that `Genesis` was created at `time = 0`

Is it possible to have a parameter for `Genesis` called `time` which is always some value, say `0`?

Currently I circumvent this as follows:

```
predicate valid(tree: Tree)
{
  match tree
    case Genesis => true
    case Node(parent, time) =>
      time > (if parent == Genesis then 0 else parent.time) && valid(parent)
}
```

However I would like to accomplish something like this:

```
predicate valid(tree: Tree)
{
  match tree
    case Genesis => true
    case Node(parent, time) =>
      time > parent.time && valid(parent)
}
```

Any leads will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add a constant field to a datatype constructor. Your best bet is probably to write a function `GetTime(tree: Tree): nat` that wraps your `if` expression.

If you give more context about your problem, there might also be a better solution.